# Objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects(When using different services)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I read a lot on this topic but I still do not understand how to use different services with own contexts. I know that if I use something like "Unit Of Work", this approach will solve my problem, but I am looking for another solution. Any help will be appreciated!

```
  public class SportCategoryService : ISportCategoryService
  {
    private IDeletableEntityRepository<SportCategory> sportCategoriesDb;
    private IDeletableEntityRepository<User> usersDb;

    public SportCategoryService(IDeletableEntityRepository<SportCategory> sportCategoriesDb, IDeletableEntityRepository<User> usersDb)
    {
        this.sportCategoriesDb = sportCategoriesDb;
        this.usersDb = usersDb;
    }

    public void AddCategoriesForUser(string[] categories, string userId)
    {
        var user = usersDb.All().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);

        foreach (var name in categories)
        {
            var currentCategory = this.sportCategoriesDb.All().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);

            if (currentCategory != null)
            {
                currentCategory.Users.Add(user);
            }
            else
            {
                sportCategoriesDb.Add(new SportCategory() { Name = name,    Users = new List<User>() { user } });
            }
        }

        sportCategoriesDb.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which EF version is used? What is in `IDeletableEntityRepository`? Is Lazy Loading enabled?

Comment: EF 6.1.3, IDeletableEntityRepository is stanandart repository with some options when deleting entities, to set flag and other stuff like date, when deleted. Lazy loading is enabled. However, I solved the problem with passing same instantion of dbcontext for both services. Acturally Ninject is doing it with the option "InRequestScope()".

       kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>  ().InRequestScope();

Comment: yes, single context is one of the options. Another one is to disable lazy loading - `user` will be a POCO object instead of proxy-class. It allows to re-attach `user` to another context.